# BERT Training checkpoint

Tags: bert-language-model

I trained my data by BERT and in the bert_output directory I got these files:

- model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt-0.index
- model.ckpt-0.meta
- model.ckpt-343.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt-343.index
- model.ckpt-343.meta
- checkpoint
- graph.pbtxt

Now, I need to determine the number of the highest-number model.ckptfile. This set of files contains the weights for the model that I trained.

My question is: How can I read the content in the .ckpt files?

---

```
export BERT_BASE_DIR=./path/to/weights/downloaded/in/step2
export TRAINED_CLASSIFIER=./bert_output/model.ckpt-[highest checkpoint number you saw]
python bert/run_classifier.py \
--task_name=cola \
--do_predict=true \
--data_dir=./data \
--vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=$TRAINED_CLASSIFIER \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--output_dir=./bert_output/
```

Comment: Why do you want to read the contents in the ckpt file?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Because I need to determine the number of the highest-number model.ckptfile and then used it for predicting step which I mentioned the code!!

Comment: You can simply look at the files right? In your case 'model.ckpt-343' is the one with the highest number